# Pop up a .aspx page from my own project using crystal repot

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to Pop up a .aspx page from my own project using crystal repot object

e.g there is an text object on crystal report VIEW ATTACHMENTS  , if user click this , a .aspx page should be pop up showing some attachments etc

Answer (score 0):

right click on the text object, click on Format Editor, and go to the Hyperlink tab.  Select the "A Website on the Internet" in the "Hyperlink type:" area.  Add the hyperlink to the "Hyperlink Information:" area.  If you need multiple hyperlinks based on different criteria you will need to set up a formula.